# How to drill down with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, menu, list, effects

I'm new to jQuery so sorry if this sounds stupid but I'm having truble drilling down to other elemnts. Paticularly I want to fade in the .menu li a:hover class with jquery.

CSS

```
.menu {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.menu li {
    float:left;
    margin-left:1px;
}
.menu li a {
    display:block;
    height:44px;
    line-height:40px;
    padding:0 5px;
    float:right;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.menu li a b {
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.menu li a:hover {
    color:#E4FFC5;
    background: url(../images/arrow.png) no-repeat center bottom;
}
.current {
    background: url(../images/arrow.png) no-repeat center bottom;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.spacer p {
    display:block;
    height:44px;
    line-height:40px;
    padding:0 5px;
    float:right;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

HTML

```
 <ul class="menu">
    <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="spacer">
        <p>|</p>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Mission &amp; Values </a></li>
    <li class="spacer">
        <p>|</p>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Caregivers</a></li>
    <li class="spacer">
        <p>|</p>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Special Programs </a></li>
    <li class="spacer">
        <p>|</p>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Enployment</a></li>
    <li class="spacer">
        <p>|</p>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $('a').mouseover(function() {
        $('.logo').animate ({opacity:'0.6'}, 'normal');
    });

    $('a').mouseout (function() {
        $('.logo').animate ({opacity:'1'}, 'normal');
        $('.menu li a:hover').fadeIn ('slow');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
$('.menu li a:hover').fadeIn ('slow');
```

Note : here you're saying 'find me all A elements currently hovered within 
a LI within a class .menu, and fade them in'

What you wanted perhaps to say is 'find me all A elements within a LI within a class .menu, and when one of them is overed, fade it in.'

I'd suggest something like

```
$('.menu li a').hover(function(){ $(this).fadeIn ('slow'); }, 
                      function(){ $(this).fadeOut('slow'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector you are looking for is

```
$("ul.menu > li > a")
```

I think you are trying to fade the anchor tag to a particular level on mouse out and rest it on mouse over. For this you can use **[fadeTo](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)** method

```
$(function() {
    $('ul.menu > li > a').hover(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo ('slow',1);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).fadeTo ('slow',0.5);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your classes around a bit you can do this:

Change hove to a class:

```
.menu li a.hover {
    background: url(../images/arrow.png) no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

Animate the font color using that background in the class, replace all your jQuery with:

```
$(function() {
  $('.menu li a').hover(function() {
    $('.logo').animate ({opacity:'0.6'}, 'normal');
    $(this).addClass("hover").animate({ color:'#E4FFC5'}, "slow");
  }, function() {
    $('.logo').animate ({opacity:'1'}, 'normal');
    $(this).removeClass("hover").animate({ color:'#fff' }, "slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox you can install [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). 
With [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) you can set breakpoints on your javascript and go line for line. Also you can inspect the DOM directly and see how the DOM is like etc.